# error trying to include angular-moment module

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I've been trying to add the `angular-moment` package to my angular app but I keep getting errors after trying to include the module. 
I ran `bower install angular-moment --save` in the project root to install the package and verified that I was indeed loading the scripts in `index.html`:

```
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

However, as soon as I add the dependency to my app definition like:

```
angular.module('starter', ['angularMoment', 'ionic', ...
```

I get a console error such as:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularMoment due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularMoment' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/nomod?p0=angularMoment
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12)
>       at http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1751:17
>       at ensure (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1675:38)
>       at module (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1749:14)
>       at http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4081:22
>       at forEach (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:20)
>       at loadModules (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4065:5)
>       at http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4082:40
>       at forEach (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:20)
>       at loadModules (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4065:5)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=angularMoment&p1=Er…F192.168.8.250%3A8100%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4065%3A5)
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12)
>       at http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4104:15
>       at forEach (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:20)
>       at loadModules (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4065:5)
>       at http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4082:40
>       at forEach (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:20)
>       at loadModules (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4065:5)
>       at createInjector (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3991:11)
>       at doBootstrap (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1438:20)
>       at bootstrap (http://192.168.8.250:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1459:12)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3A…

The angularMoment module is defined so I'm not really sure why I'm getting this error?

*The full includes look like:*

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-logX/release/amd/angular-logX.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-underscore-module/angular-underscore-module.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/configuration.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you adding the `moment` scripts BEFORE the code it self?

Comment: Yep, all the bower modules are loaded before any app specific stuff (I put it in the edit now).

Comment: Is there any other console error or 404?

Comment: I think it's linked to this bug, https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/36  because you have requirejs on your scripts.

Comment: That was it. I needed to move `require.js` below the `moment.js` include. If you put this as an answer I can choose it.

Comment: I've made it has an answer, as it seems to be helpfull !

Answer (score 2):

I think it's linked to this bug, http://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/36 because you have requirejs on your scripts.

[EDIT]

Has you find out, you have to move `require.js` below the `moment.js` include

[NOTICE]

This was originaly a comment but as it seems to be helpfull to various people I've made it has an answer for more clarity.